# Node js array dashboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I'm doing the backend of my app with node js. In this case i'm trying to get the typical dashboard like facebook, instagram,....
Where for one user i'm trying to get the users that he follows. And when i get the array of users following, i find the "recetas" that they have (one user can have more than one). And finally i add all this recetas in an array but the problem is that is returning me empty.

```
getDashboard = function (req, res) {
  var myarray = new Array();
  //myarray = [];
  User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      res.send(404, 'User not found');
    }
    else {
      var a = user.following;
      a.forEach(function (current_value) {
        Receta.find({ "user_id": current_value._id }, function (err, recetas) {
          if (!err) {
            recetas.forEach(function (receta) {
              myarray.push(receta);
            }
          } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
          }
        });
      })
      res.send(myarray);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you (please do it yourself next time), and you are missing a closing `)` after the `forEach`. So  it looks like this in the original `.forEach(function() {...}` without the closing `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with a common async issue. `Receta.find` is asynchronous, it is not a blocking operation, so `res.send` is called before all of your `Receta.find` calls have completed. You can get around this issue by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), assuming they are available in your version of Node:

```
var a = user.following;
var promises = a.map(function(current_value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Receta.find({"user_id":current_value._id}, function (err, recetas) {
            if(!err) {
                resolve(recetas);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(allData) {
    res.send(allData);
}).catch(function(error) {
    res.send(error);
});
```

If native Promises aren't available, you can use a library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

Comment: Thanks this helped me!! but in the case receta(for each insde the find) who i can do it because one user can have more than one receta and for the moment i would have something like that [[{obj1},{obj2}],[{ob3}]] and i want this [{obj1},{obj2},{obj3}]

Answer (score 1):

`res.send(myarray);` is being called before `a.forEach` completes due to  Receta.find which is I/O.

call res.send only when the loop is finished and recetas returned.